# Gate-Level Sim: Hold time violation between testbench and first registers?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga, asic

I have a testbench that acts as a slave to an AXI-Stream master as given below. It is written without classes to work with both Icarus Verilog and Verilator. This works well in randomized logic simulation.

Problem: When we do gate-level with the same testbench, many signals are undefined.

In this testbench, right @(posedge clk), I read the signals into variables, then give a #10ps delay to avoid race conditions and write values into signals. Is there any chance this might be causing hold time violations when simulating hardware with actual input & output delays? If yes, what is the best way of fixing it?

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module DMA_S2M #(
  parameter  BUS_WIDTH=8, PROB_READY=20,
  parameter  BYTES_PER_BEAT = BUS_WIDTH/8
)(
    input  logic aclk, aresetn,
    output logic m_ready,
    input  logic m_valid, m_last,
    input  logic [BYTES_PER_BEAT-1:0][7:0] m_data, 
    input  logic [BYTES_PER_BEAT-1:0] m_keep
);

  longint unsigned i_bytes = 0;
  bit done = 0;

  import "DPI-C" function void set_byte (longint unsigned addr, byte data);

  task axis_pull (input longint unsigned base_addr, input int bytes_per_transfer);
    m_ready = 0;
    wait(aresetn);
    
    while (!done) begin

      @(posedge aclk)
      if (m_ready && m_valid) begin  // read at posedge
        for (int i=0; i < BYTES_PER_BEAT; i=i+1)
          if (m_keep[i]) begin
            set_byte(base_addr + i_bytes, m_data[i]);
            i_bytes  += 1;
          end
        if (m_last) done = 1;
      end

      #10ps // delay before writing
      m_ready = $urandom_range(0,999) < PROB_READY;
    end

    {done, i_bytes} = 0;
  endtask
endmodule
```

Comment: impossible to say with the code you posted.  you need to debug your gate sim with waveforms

Comment: 10ps is not much.  Recommend increasing little by little until you approach the negative edge of the clock. If you get to the negative edge then something else is going on.

Comment: Did you compile the vendors simulation primitives library?  The post synthesis simulation is not simulating language, but rather is simulating a particular combination of the vendors primitives ('gates').

Comment: What is the point of the 10ps delay? Why don't you just generate it at `posedge aclk`? Isn't that how it will be generated in the real system? Is your concern that you also sample `m_ready`?